# Push notification from PHP to Angular

Tags: php, angular, websocket, zend-framework, client-server

I have an API written in PHP (Laminas API Tools/Zend Framework 3) which generates PDF report.
This action is triggered by an Angular client via AJAX call to the API.

It takes a while to generate the PDF, so everything is processed in the background asynchronously (in a beanstalkd queue) and once the PDF generation is completed the server sends a notification email to the user.

How can I send a notification directly from PHP to the particular Angular client which triggered the PDF generation action, in a real time, without polling?

Do I need to use websockets?
Any example of using websockets+PHP+Angular together?

Comment: You can do it using pusher ( https://pusher.com/ ). If you don't want to use third party services you can do it using Ratchet  ( http://socketo.me/ ). There are examples in both websites